# Node JS not terminating after a chain of function calls

Tags: node.js, error-handling, try-catch, freeze, function-calls

My code structure is something like this:

```
    A();

function A() {
    try {
        // something that can generate an error
        console.log('\nIn A()');
        B();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function B() {
    try {
        console.log('\nIn B()');
        C()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function C() {
    try {
        console.log('\nIn C()');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

What I have observed is, if an exception gets generated, it comes into the catch block, prints the console.log. But does not terminate the code. I have read that catch won't terminate, but since the control is not transferred elsewhere, why does the process hang? I also tried making a function that logs the error and is called from catch block. It goes into the function & hangs again.

I am new to error handling in Node JS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I paste that code in a file say `test.js` and run `node test.js`, I get console logs printed and my process terminates. So, What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with the cascading function calls. It was because the read stream used for taking user input from the commandline was not closed. Node does not terminate if a stream is left open or any asynchronous call is yet to be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided code run's without error.

```js
   A();

function A() {
    try {
        // something that can generate an error
        console.log('\nIn A()');
        B();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function B() {
    try {
        console.log('\nIn B()');
        C()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function C() {
    try {
        console.log('\nIn C()');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. Say, I am reading a file in the try block of function A. If I give the wrong path, it'll go in catch. The utility hangs after printing the error in catch. How to debug such issues?

Comment: You can exit node apps with `process.exit(0)` or `process.exit(1)` (without or with error respectively) or with `process.kill()`.

Comment: I just want to debug why it hangs. Like you mentioned it runs here, but in my utility which has a similar structure it hangs. Ideally it should have terminated after printing the console in catch. But it doesn't. Any idea what the issue could be? What could be the possible reasons? :(

Comment: I guess there a leak somewhere. I am having a lot of asynchronous code running in the function calls involving file reads and writes. Probably, the stream isn't closing. For now, I have fixed with process.exit().